# Converting GPS to ENU

Tags: android, gps, coordinates

I want to create android application "Points of interest". I've read many different tutorials, and I do not understand why I need to convert GPS coordinates to ECEF and then to ENU. Can you explain, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you think that you need to do that? I don't see any reason.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko GPS coordinates are in geographic coordinate system, but for displaying them on the screen I need them in cartesian coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geospatial coordinate systems are a big topic, but the main choice between systems such as ECEF and ENU is about whether you want to describe a large region of the Earth's surface or just a small region.

When Android provides a [geolocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) via the [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) API, it typically does this using latitude/longitude/altitude which is ideal for representing any point over the Earth's surface, but is a "polar" or "geodetic" coordinate system that isn't ideal for plotting 2D locations. Standard [techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates) allow this coordinate system to be converted into ECEF, which is another coordinate system which is suitable for the whole globe, but is "cartesian" so can be rotated and scaled using much simpler mathematical operations than the original latitude/longitude/altitude coordinates.

Earth-Centred Earth Fixed ([ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF)) uses a coordinate system with its origin at the Earth's centre, so that any point on the ground will have coordinate values that are typically in the millions of metres. This is great for describing satellite orbits, or locations that span multiple continents, but not very convenient for 2D plots of points of interest within a town or city.

If you want to draw a 2D map of a small region of the Earth's surface, then the East-North-Up coordinate system may be much more convenient. To use this, you need a reference location (such as the centre of a particular city) about which the local East/North/Up directions can be defined. Those then provide a set of x/y/z axes, where the x & y axes might be directly converted into the 2D screen coordinates. Obviously, as the region of interest grows larger (e.g. more than 100km), the effects of the Earth's curvature become more noticeable, and an ENU coordinate system will be less useful. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum) for more info.

Moving from an ECEF to ENU coordinate system can be done by a simple set of matrix additions & multiplications which can be computed from the ECEF location of the centre of the map, and the unit vectors in the east/north/up directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way on Java

```
public List<Double> convertGpsToECEF(double lat, double longi, float alt) {

    double a=6378.1;
    double b=6356.8;
    double N;
    double e= 1-(Math.pow(b, 2)/Math.pow(a, 2));
    N= a/(Math.sqrt(1.0-(e*Math.pow(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat)), 2))));
    double cosLatRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double cosLongiRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longi));
    double sinLatRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double sinLongiRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(longi));
    double x =(N+0.001*alt)*cosLatRad*cosLongiRad;
    double y =(N+0.001*alt)*cosLatRad*sinLongiRad;
    double z =((Math.pow(b, 2)/Math.pow(a, 2))*N+0.001*alt)*sinLatRad;

    List<Double> ecef= new ArrayList<>();
    ecef.add(x);
    ecef.add(y);
    ecef.add(z);

    return ecef;


}


public List<Double> convertECEFtoENU(List<Double> ecefUser, List<Double> ecefPOI, double lat, double longi){

    double cosLatRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double cosLongiRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longi));
    double sinLatRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double sinLongiRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(longi));


    List<Double> vector = new ArrayList<>();

    vector.add(ecefUser.get(0)-ecefPOI.get(0));
    vector.add(ecefUser.get(1)-ecefPOI.get(1));
    vector.add(ecefUser.get(2)-ecefPOI.get(2));

    double e= vector.get(0)*(-sinLongiRad)+vector.get(0)*(cosLongiRad);
    double n= vector.get(0)*(-sinLatRad)*(cosLongiRad)+vector.get(1)*(-sinLatRad)*(sinLongiRad)+vector.get(2)*cosLatRad;
    double u= vector.get(0)*(cosLatRad)*(cosLongiRad)+vector.get(1)*(cosLatRad)*(sinLongiRad)+vector.get(2)*sinLatRad;


    List<Double> enu= new ArrayList<>();
    enu.add(e);
    enu.add(n);
    enu.add(u);

    return enu;
    }
```